# Wordpress - How to save user profile form from a front-end form?

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, user-profile

I'm new to Wordpress and php and I'm trying to build a form where a user can update its interests from the front end (the form would be displayed in a custom WooCommerce endpoint).
What i have managed so far :

1. From WordPress user administration, I can display, save and update
   user's interests
2. I created a custom WooCommerce endpoint and
   displayed in a form the list of possible interests with checkboxes
   displaying what is registered for the user

However, I can't get the form to save the modifications... I think I'm missing something in the way forms are constructed (involving JS or Ajax, maybe?).

Here is my php code so far (from my custom endpoint: my-account-mesinterets.php):

```
<form method="post" id="adduser" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <?php
            $auth_id = $post->post_author;
            $data = get_user_meta($auth_id, 'MyInterests', true); ?>
                        
        <label for="wood-sculpture">Travail du bois (sculpture, marqueterie)</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="wood-sculpture" value="wood-sculpture" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('wood-sculpture', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>
                
        <label for="wood-creation">Travail du bois (création de meubles et d'objets)</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="wood-creation" value="wood-creation" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('wood-creation', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>

        <label for="jewelry">Bijouterie (avec métaux précieux, bois, pierres, autres...)</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="jewelry" value="jewelry" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('jewelry', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>
                        
        <label for="deco">Déco</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="deco" value="deco" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('deco', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>

        <label for="pottery">Poterie</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="pottery" value="pottery" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('pottery', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>

        <label for="metal">Travail du métal</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="metal" value="metal" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('metal', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>
                        
        <label for="music-instruments">Création d'instruments de musique</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="music-instruments" value="music-instruments" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('music-instruments', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>
                        
        <label for="leather">Travail du cuir</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="leather" value="leather" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('leather', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>
                       
        <label for="floral-art">Art floral</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="floral-art" value="floral-art" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('floral-art', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>
                        
        <label for="other">Autres</label>
        <input name="MyInterests[]" type="checkbox" id="other" value="other" <?php
        if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
            if (in_array('other', $data)) {
                echo 'checked';
            } ?> >
        <br>
                        
    </fieldset>
    
    <p class="form-submit">
        <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="submit button" value="<?php _e('Update', 'profile'); ?>" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user' ) ?>
        <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
    </p>

</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm really stuck here. Thanks a lot!